# Remove file from folder using python

Tags: python

How can I remove files in a folder based on CSV conditions?
For example, all files that are less than 50 in length and width.

Files = pd.read_csv('records.csv')

The file path exists in the CSV file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0CfI.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), and provide a [mre]. "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.